# I have a string variable word="APA"

Tags: c++, string, overflow

When I do the calculation: `1-word.length();`
Visual studio prints 4294967294, instead it supposed to print -2.

Wen I do the calculation: `1+word.length();`
Visual studio prints 4, what it supposed to be.

Why when I subtract length from 1 gives me that number and how can I fix it?

Note: I use C++ and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: See the differences in the example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81fed3e2f745a90e). Since [`length()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns a `size_t` you are performing an arithmetic operation with an unsigned type unless you cast it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ good to see you're back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the result of the expression `1 - word.length()` is an `unsigned` type because `length()` returns [an `unsigned` integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). So `-2` wraps around and you get your `4294967294`.